# How to insert an IF statement that involves text with script?

Tags: google-sheets

How do you insert an `IF` statement that requires a formula to read text in an alternate cell via script? This is a small portion of a formula I am inserting and I would like it to be to be able to insert `=IF(AND($S$2="SOME WORD",F25/8...` and so on but if I put the quotes around the text as required to get the formula to work correctly when it is inserted, it causes errors. Is there anyway to do this?

//Set formulas in columns that require formulas

```
sheet.getRange("H25").setFormula("=IF(AND($S$2=1,F25/8=TRUNC(F25/8)),(((F25/8)+(G25/2))*$N$4),IF(AND($S$2=1,(F25-6)/8=TRUNC((F25-6)/8)),((((F2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to put "SOME WORD" as the contents to another cell, say $A$1, and reference that in your formula? So test if $S$2 = $A$1? Would that work for you?

EDIT

So put your very long string for the formula into more manageable chunks.

```
s2isOneStr = "$s$2 = " & """" & "Sewer" & """"
s2isZeroStr = "$s$2 = " & """" & "Culvert" & """"

ifstr1 = "IF(AND(" & s2isOneStr & ",F25/8=TRUNC(F25/8)),(((F25/8)+(G25/2))*$N$4),"

ifStr2 = "IF(AND(‌​" & s2isOneStr & ",(F25-6)/8=TRUNC((F25-6)/8)),((((F25-6)/8)+1+(G25/2))*$N$4),"

ifStr3 = "IF(AND(‌​" & s2isOneStr & ",(‌​F25-12)/8=TRUNC((F25-12)/8)),((((F25-12)/8)+2+(G25/2))*$N$4),"

//Keep going with all the ifs!
```

Then you combine all these strings in your formula, might be easier to debug should you ever need to change the formula...

```
masterStr =  "=" & ifStr1 & ifStr2 & etc etc

.setFormula(masterStr);
```

This way the code most likely to change is right at the top...

Comment: Might be easier to edit the sheet if it does in case "SOME WORD" changes then you just edit the sheet rather than hunt for instances of it in formulae. Nick.

Comment: No that won't work in this instance. The word that it is searching for is in a drop down that has multiple options. So if the drop down = Sewer, then one answer, if the drop down = culvert, then another answer.

Comment: Oh I see so if this was in a cell you'd put =IF(A1="Some Word", true, false) but you want to specify a string to put in the setFormula? You could write .setFormula("=IF(" & """" & "Some Word" & """" & " rest of your formula")

Comment: 4 quotes together in there.

Comment: I think I kind of see what you are saying. I believe I may end up with a serious amount of quotes in my instance. I am using a formula a coworker had in a spreadsheet and trying to automate some of his spreadsheet. The formula is quite long. Here is the whole formula:

Comment: .setFormula("=IF(AND($S$2=1,F25/8=TRUNC(F25/8)),(((F25/8)+(G25/2))*$N$4),IF(AND($S$2=1,(F25-6)/8=TRUNC((F25-6)/8)),((((F25-6)/8)+1+(G25/2))*$N$4),IF(AND($S$2=1,(F25-12)/8=TRUNC((F25-12)/8)),((((F25-12)/8)+2+(G25/2))*$N$4),if(AND($S$2=1,(F25-18)/8=TRUNC((F25-18)/8)),((((F25-18)/8)+3+(G25/2))*$N$4),IF(AND($S$2=0,F25/8=TRUNC(F25/8)),(((F25/8)+(G25/2))*$O$4),if(AND($S$2=0,(F25-6)/8=TRUNC((F25-6)/8)),((((F25-6)/8)+3+(G25/2))*$O$4),if(AND($S$2=0,(F25-12)/8=TRUNC((F25-12)/8)),((((F25-12)/8)+3+(G25/2))*$O$4),if(AND($S$2=0,(F25-18)/8=TRUNC((F25-18)/8)),((((F25-18)/8)+3+(G25/2))*$O$4),0))))))))");

Comment: I would like to replace the $S$2=1 with $S$2="Sewer" and the $S$2=0 with $S$2="Culvert"

Comment: I will move this to a new question as I need to expand on it to include referring to the last row also. Thanks for the help